UEFI Read USB Port Count
I am writing a UEFI program that needs to read the actual number of USB ports. How should I do it? I have used GetCapability, but it reads extra USB ports.
My goal is to write a function that can return the actual number of USB ports.

The extra USB ports may exist on your motherboard internally, they may not have sockets attached at your case. Some may have internal peripherals connected and some may just end in a header or pads with nothing connected. I don't think you can really differentiate between those cases universally!

@CherryDT So, does this mean I can only define a variable and directly write the number into it?
